# Select column and apply "General"-format to all cells + put macro on a button

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am looking to do the following:

1. When pressing a button, the Macro should be activated.
2. The Macro selects Column H in Sheet 2 (same workbook). Not the whole column, just until data goes. The last line with data can be determined if after that line the next 10 lines are empty.
3. For this selection, the "General" format is applied to every cell.
4. After this, the same runs through for Column G.
5. The Macro ends.

I think it should be easily possible, but I am especially struggling with the "determining last line with data" part, as if applied to the whole column the PC massively slows down.

Then, I am unsure where I should put the code (Sheet, ThisWorkbook, Module) as best practice.

Comment: Is there anything after the blank 10 cells? If not, then you would just be looking for the last used cell in that column. Is it always specifically 10 blank cells. You mention Sheet 2; how is this related to your question?

Comment: Won't work because sometimes there are up to 7 cells left empty in between until next datapoint comes.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. It is not important if there are less than 10 blanks between values, code can get around this. The question is, is there anything after the 10 blank cells that you are looking for - which tells us that there is no more data? Or are you looking for SPECIFICALLY 10 blank cells, even though there may be other values beyond these.

Comment: Ah, got it, there is nothing after the 10 blanks so it could be 15 or 100...

Comment: Thing is each month new data is added at the end, thus I do not want to hardcode the range to a fixed line but also not want to use the whole column as this slows everything down a lot

Answer (score 8):

There are other ways to do this, but the easiest generally is to choose a LARGE row number (will there ever be more than 20,000 rows?) and navigate upwards.

```
Range("H2", Range("H20000").End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "General"
Range("G2", Range("G20000").End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "General"
```

But you can also just format the entire columns:

```
Range("G:H").NumberFormat = "General"
```

this doesn't (these days) impact the size of the file.

You want to click a button of the sheet to run the macro, so you could use a Form Controls, Button and the code would then be in a standard module.

**Added** (from my comment):

This would work:

```
Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("G:H")).NumberFormat = "General"
```

but it requires some error-handling, just in case these ranges don't intersect.

Responding to 2 further questions in comments:

```
Worksheets("Whatever").Activate
```

If `NumberFormat` applied to the column doesn't work then there must be something else going on that interferes - or perhaps the data was *faulty* when imported(?). Try:

```
Application.CalculateFull
```

or just use the specific range:

```
Range("..").Calculate
```

If this doesn't work then you may have to copy the data to a blank column and delete the old column. Or perhaps copy and paste (maybe values) into the same range.

Comment: Okay, two follow up: How do I get to the sheet as the button will be in a different sheet? And is it enough to set .NumberFormat? Because if I mark the column and set number format I still would need to go the every cell, click in it and then press Enter to have it applied. Just selecting the column and choosing the NumberFormat was not enough

Answer (score 1):

You can format all cells in columns G and H as general without selecting the range or the sheet. You should always avoid selecting anything in your VBA code.

The de facto standard way of finding the last row with data is to start at bottom of the sheet and go up from there.

The following finds the last cell with data on sheet2 in both columns G and H. We use the greatest of the two to set the range we will use to apply general formatting.

```
Sub GeneralFormatForAllPopulatedCells()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim g As Long, h As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    g = ws.Range("G" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    h = ws.Range("H" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If g > h Then
        lastRow = g
    Else
        lastRow = h
    End If

    Set rng = ws.Range("G1:H" & lastRow)
    rng.NumberFormat = "General"


End Sub
```

You should place your code in a module, and make sure that `Option Explicit` appears at the top of the module so that variable declaration is required. You can turn this on for all modules by opening the options dialog from within  the VBA editor: **Tools --> Options** and then checking the box next to **Require Variable Declaration**.

Comment: It worked and sets both columns to General formatting but the above described problem applies: Even though the column is defined as General, I would need to click on every individual cell and press enter to actually change the format. How can I solve this?

Comment: Plans changed, I could skip the formatting and do the following instead: When I found the last data cell using the above code, I want to use the following formular in column AA up the last data row (not beyond it). How can I do it?  `=IF(N3="";"ERR";IF(ISERROR(VALUE(N3));"ERR";VALUE(N3)))`  In this case, N3 should be Nx up to the point where lastRow is reached. Thereafter now formular should be applied

Comment: You shouldn't need to click into each cell to apply the new format. Do you have automatic calculation turned off? As far as your change of plans goes, you should post a new question to get help on that.