# Macro to find end data and convert all selected into number format

Tags: excel, vba

My data always starts in cell E2, and goes an undetermined amount of rows across, and undetermined amount of columns down. I want a macro to find the last row with data, and the last column with data, and highlight from E2 to the ends of the data, and convert it all into number format.

I have found how to find the last cell with data in the row, and column. but I don't know how to select the data range from E2 to the last data range.

Comment: Check this URL for select data range and formatting the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176045/vba-select-column-and-apply-general-format-to-all-cells-put-macro-on-a-butt

Comment: You seem to have two questions in your question, I answered what seemed like the real need.

Answer (score 0):

If `Rng` is your last cell, then

```
Range(Range("E2"), Rng)).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure there is a simpler way but this one works:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 2

While ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Value <> ""
 i = i + 1
Wend

ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E" & (i - 1)).Select
```

Even simpler if you just record it:

```
Range("E2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```